# Rolling back to an old revision in Mercurial (like git reset)

Tags: git, version-control, mercurial

Using git, I can throw away a mistaken or accidental commit using a command like

```
git reset --soft HEAD^
```

which resets the current branch (such as `master`) to the current revision's parent commit `HEAD^` without touching the working tree – you can replace `--soft` with `--hard` if you want to obliterate the working tree as well.

In addition, if I want to get rid of more than one commit, I can use a command like

```
git reset --hard 53b94d0
```

which brings me back exactly to commit 53b94d0 as if I had never committed anything after that.

What's the Mercurial (hg) equivalent?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Though Mercurial doesn’t provide an easy alternative and shies away from the idea of mutable history, there are a few ways to achieve something close. In this post, I’ll outline a few of them.

## hg rollback

If you specifically want to undo your last commit, you can use:

```
hg rollback
```

which will undo the commit (which doesn't touch the working tree – you should be able to follow it with a `hg revert --all` or `hg update -C` if you want to reset the entire working directory as well).

## hg clone -r

Suppose you want to reset your repository called `giraffe` to revision 77182fb7451f. If you `cd` into the parent directory and run:

```
hg clone -r 77182fb7451f giraffe new-giraffe
cp giraffe/.hg/hgrc new-giraffe/.hg/
```

then you'll end up with new-giraffe, a repository at revision 77182fb7451f. (The `cp` is necessary to ensure that new-giraffe `paths` (like git's "remotes") correctly point to the origin repo instead of to the `giraffe` folder as it would by default.)

This is faster than recloning from the internet because it only copies files locally on your disk (and on many systems, hard-links them to save even more time and space), but can still be really time-consuming if your repository is large.

## hg strip

If you want to do more complicated things with modifying the commit history (which is somewhat frowned on in the hg world, by the way), first enable the [Mercurial Queues extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/MqExtension/) by adding the following lines to your `.hgrc` (there's no need to specify a path after the equals sign):

```
[extensions]                                                                    
mq =
```

This gives you (among other useful things) the `hg strip` command to completely remove a changeset and all of its descendants from a repository. Thus you can use a command like:

```
hg strip 1cc72d33ea76
```

if 1cc72d33ea76 is the first "bad" changeset in your repository that you want to remove.

Unfortunately, it's often hard to remove exactly the right changesets using this method and it's all too easy to end up with multiple heads (which you can view using `hg heads`), requiring tedious repeated application of `hg strip` before you can get to where you want to be with no extra heads.

## hg strip using revsets

Using [hg revsets](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/help/revsets) you can delete all the ancestors of `.` (the current revision) which are *not* ancestors of the revision you want to revert to, using a command like:

```
hg strip "ancestors(.) and not ancestors(77182fb7451f)"
```

Make sure to first run:

```
hg log -r "ancestors(.) and not ancestors(77182fb7451f)"
```

which will show you all the changesets that `hg strip` would remove, so you can make sure you don't irreparably harm your commit history (because you have backups… right?).

Comment: So, in hg the reset-equivalent rollback/strip is more than just changing what commit a branch tag points to, there's some actual alteration to the database involved?